# How to show created since with custom output format on docker ps?

Tags: docker

I configure `psFormat` on `~/.docker/config.json` like this:

```json
{
  "psFormat": "table {{.ID}}\\t{{.Image}}\\t{{.CreatedAt}}\\t{{.Status}}\\t{{.Ports}}\\t{{.Names}}"
}
```

The problem is `CreatedAt` column show exact date instead of how long the container was created:

```
CREATED AT
2023-05-21 04:26:47 +0700 +07
```

But what I want is:

```
CREATED
About a minute ago
```

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#format) does not tell how to display in this format.

Comment: I don't think it is supported, you will have to edit this by yourself, an easy simple way is to use `jq` like this `jq -r '. | fromdateiso8601 | strftime("%H:%M:%S")'` this can be executed in the command line after the inspect element, the `fromdateiso8601 `  will convert from iso8601 timestamp format to Unix and the `strftime` will format into more human-readable

Comment: But it is displayed in the format I wanted by default (without `psFormat`).

Comment: I dont think its supported by docker, will wait to see if someone has an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake,

instead of using the column `Created`, you're looking for `RunningFor`, here's an example using `--format`, but it'll work too in `config.json`:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.RunningFor}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

See the documentation (which does not give great details about the format, I know you read it, but it lists alternative columns you can try): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#format

> Valid placeholders for the Go template are listed below:
>
> - `Placeholder`   `Description`
> - `.CreatedAt`    Time when the container was created.
> - `.RunningFor`   Elapsed time since the container was started.